# jquery simulate click on html anchor tag

Tags: jquery, click

I've been trying to simulate click on a tag and this is not working as i need it to.
my anchor tag looks like this

```
<a href="/dl/pic.jpg" target="_blank" download="file.jpg"> Download this pic </a>
```

a normral `$("a").click()` or `trigger('click')` wont work here.Any ideas?
**EDIT**
I need to trigger a click on this Anchor tag and causing the file to download, i dont need to add another onClick function.

Comment: $('a').on('click', function(e){e.preventDefault();alert("clicked");});

Answer (score 9):

Using native js click event works:

http://jsfiddle.net/n6FKg/

```
$('a').get(0).click();
```

Comment: cant use indicator, this is dynamically created and doesnt have fixed position in order of Anchors

Comment: I'm just telling you that using jquery to trigger click on anchor doesn't work but using js native click() works. How you target this element is up to you. In you question, you said: $("a").click() wont work. Then i show you how to make it works... If you have more than one anchor to trigger click, then use a loop from get()

Comment: By position, you mean index??? The question is how do you want to target a specific anchor? Sorry but your question is really too vague and incomplete.

Comment: Yaah, it did worked, can you guide me about 'what does get(0) does'?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using JavaScript itself by adding an id attribute

```
<a id="download" href="/dl/pic.jpg" download="file.jpg"> Download this pic </a>

document.getElementById("download").click();
```

Answer (score 0):

add the path to the file to be downloaded to the `href`attribute not to `download` attribute

```
<a href="/dl/file.jpg" target="_blank"> Download this pic </a>
```

Comment: do u have the intended file kept at that path? coz this is the only way a file download should work?

Answer (score 0):

Few options here:

1. The link is added dynamically, in that case binding `click` won't work, you need to do something like this:

   ```
    ('#linkContainer').on('click','a',function(){//do stuff});
   ```
2. the click does work, but since its an `a` tag, it has a default behaviour and it goes to the `href`, so you need to add in the function `e.preventDefault`

Comment: you didnt understand the question, i dont need adding another funcationality , i just need to trigger this file download from other place.

Comment: You didn't understand my answer, as it does exactly what you need, with no extra functionality added

Comment: i need to default click to go to the href..i need to trigger the file to download.

Comment: That is not what your question says, please update your question and explain exactly what you need